# Select Max date and Min date after point in time

Tags: sql

I have customer support data, showing the customer ID, the ID number of their customer support ticket, the time the ticket was entered, and the time(s) that customer support representatives documented the support services they provided. Some tickets require multiple instances of support, and some customers have multiple tickets

| Customer_ID | Ticket | Ticket_entry_Time | Serv_doc_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1/10/2022 20:45 | 1/11/2022 08:00 |
| 1 | 10 | 1/10/2022 20:45 | 1/11/2022 12:30 |
| 1 | 10 | 1/10/2022 20:45 | 1/16/2022 10:30 |
| 2 | 11 | 2/15/2022 16:30 | 2/15/2022 17:10 |
| 2 | 11 | 2/15/2022 16:30 | 2/17/2022 19:45 |
| 1 | 22 | 1/18/2022 10:20 | 1/20/2022 09:00 |
| 1 | 22 | 1/18/2022 10:20 | 1/21/2022 11:40 |

I want to group the data by customer ID, ticket, and entry time to show the first service document time, and last service document time, like this:

| Customer_ID | Ticket | Ticket_entry_Time | first_serv_time | last_serv_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1/10/2022 20:45 | 1/11/2022 08:00 | 1/16/2022 10:30 |
| 2 | 11 | 2/15/2022 16:30 | 2/15/2022 17:10 | 2/17/2022 19:45 |
| 1 | 22 | 1/18/2022 10:20 | 1/20/2022 09:00 | 1/21/2022 11:40 |

I have tried:

```
    select customer_id, ticket, ticket_entry_time, min(serv_doc_time) as first_serv_time, 
    max(serv_doc_time) as last_serv_time
    from table 
    GROUP BY customer_id, ticket, ticket_entry_time;
```

I am looking for help on how to partition the query so that the first_serv_time is greater than the ticket_entry_time for each ticket.
Thank you!

Comment: `min{case when serv_doc_time > ticket_entry_time then serv_doc_time end)`

Comment: On some platforms you can also write: `min(serv_doc_time) filter (where serv_doc_time > ticket_entry_time)`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'partition the query'? if you want to filter for those result rows satisfying your criteria you can use 'HAVING', if you want the separate rows for those with first_serv_time is greater than the ticket_entry_time  and for those with first_serv_time is not greater than the ticket_entry_time you can first run a subquery to categorise. Maybe you could show expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use partition like code below:

```
WITH RankedSupport AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Ticket, Ticket_entry_Time ORDER BY Serv_doc_time) AS rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Ticket, Ticket_entry_Time ORDER BY Serv_doc_time DESC) AS rn_desc
    FROM CustomerSupport
)
SELECT 
    Customer_ID,
    Ticket,
    Ticket_entry_Time,
    MIN(CASE WHEN rn_asc = 1 THEN Serv_doc_time END) AS first_serv_time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_desc = 1 THEN Serv_doc_time END) AS last_serv_time
FROM RankedSupport
GROUP BY Customer_ID, Ticket, Ticket_entry_Time
ORDER BY Ticket, Customer_ID, Ticket_entry_Time;
```

Here is the [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/hI1jHFvX)